# Value must be set for boolean attributes with Typescript and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript3.0

I have a pretty simple copy and paste bit of code from Material UI that I'm trying to get to work with Typescript. I have a `MediaCard` component (renamed to `DisplayCard`).

When I compile the code, I am getting this error: `(34,23): Value must be set for boolean attributes`.

I am having some difficulty figuring out the source of this error, as I'm not sure which attribute value needs to be set...

Here's the code:

App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import DisplayCard from "./components/DisplayCard";

const App = () => {
  return <DisplayCard />;
};

export default App;
```

DisplayCard.tsx

```
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";
import * as React from "react";

import { createStyles, withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = createStyles({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 140
  }
});

function DisplayCard(props: any) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image='/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg'
          title='Contemplative Reptile'
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='h2'>
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography component='p'>
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size='small' color='primary'>
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size='small' color='primary'>
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}

DisplayCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(DisplayCard);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it is referring to this line `<Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='h2'>`.

When you set an attribute like `gutterBottom` it is inferred to be `gutterBottom={true}`. Since you are using TypeScript, the gods are angry at you for not being explicit, so try explicitly setting the attribute.

```
<Typography gutterBottom={true} variant='h5' component='h2'>
```

Hopefully that will eliminate the error.

Comment: Is there a way to configure typescript to allow that? Or why shouldn't we do that?